# PowerShell 5 passing Datetime parameters in

Tags: powershell, datetime

Running the following ps1 but the datetime parameter is resuting in an error.

Debug shows the date is correct ($earlydate = the date I entered)

The HostIP parameter is being passed so it seems there is a special trick necessary for passing the datetime that I don't know.

The error I receive is:

> Cannot validate argument on parameter 'After'. The argument is null or
>   empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the
>   command again.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
param( 
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] 
    [string]$HostIP,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [datetime]$earlydate,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [datetime]$latedate
)

Invoke-Command {Get-EventLog Security -After $earlydate -Before $latedate} -ComputerName $HostIP | 
Export-Csv c:\Events\$HostIP.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Invoke-Command {Get-EventLog Security -After $using:earlydate -Before $using:latedate}
```

$earlydate & $latedate variable is defined on your machine not on remote machine. Remote machine doesn't inherit the variables automatically, so variable on the remote machine will be null.

Comment: Perfect!  This works, thank you so much for responding so quickly too!

Answer (score 0):

Your script is looking for a datetime type and I am thinking you are passing in a string. If you want to pass in a string convert it to datetime inside your function otherwise pass in a datetime object such as:

```
(Get-Date -year 2017 -month 9 -day 15)
```

Comment: Thank you for responding John, I had looked at this option from other questions but couldn't make it work for me.  It's definitely going in my notes as I continue to learn PowerShell though.